# How to remove span when generating HtmlGenericControls from Code Behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have this peace of code which generates a dropdown menu, Unfortunately I'm running into issues because `span` tags are being generated at the creation of each HtmlGenericControl.

This is my code to generate the HtmlGenericControls:

```
    string _touid = Request.QueryString["touid"];
    string _group_array = Connections.isp_GET_VALUE("TRSTR", "", "", "");
    string _tour_array = _group_array.Replace(" ", "");

    HtmlGenericControl _ul = new HtmlGenericControl();
    _ul.InnerHtml = "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";

    tour_holder.Controls.Add(_ul);

    string[] groups = _tour_array.Split(',');
    foreach (string group in groups)
    {
        string _tournoment_string = Connections.isp_GET_VALUE("TRNAM", group, "", "");

        HtmlGenericControl _li = new HtmlGenericControl();
        _li.InnerHtml = "<li><a href=\"Management.aspx?cid=" + _cid + "&touid=" + group + "\">" + _tournoment_string + "</a></li>";

        tour_holder.Controls.Add(_li);
    }
    HtmlGenericControl _ul_ = new HtmlGenericControl();
    _ul_.InnerHtml = "</ul>";
    tour_holder.Controls.Add(_ul_);
```

Below is the HTML output:

```
<span><ul class="dropdown-menu"></span>
   <span><li><a href="Management.aspx?cid=&touid=1">FIFA World Cup Brasil 2014                      </a></li>
</span>
   <span><li><a href="Management.aspx?cid=&touid=2">FIFA U-20 World Cup New Zealand 2015              </a></li></span>
   <span><li><a href="Management.aspx?cid=&touid=3">FIFA Woman's World Cup Canada 2015                </a></li></span> 
<span></ul></span>
</div>
```

How can I remove the `span` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572073/htmlgenericcontrol-without-tag).

Try passing the HTML tag the constructor instead of using the InnerHtml property like that:

```
HtmlGenericControl _ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
```